# Unable to auto-config arch from toolchain

Tags: android, android-ndk, cygwin

I'm trying to configuration toolchain in Cygwin for Android NDK.
I use of this [tutorial](http://www.ikravets.com/computer-life/programming/2014/01/18/an-android-cross-compiling-environment-on-windowsunix-like-systems-using-ndk).
when I run the following command:

> ./make-standalone-toolchain.sh --platform=android-9 --install-dir=c:/android-toolchain --ndk-dir=c:/android-ndk-r10d/

It shows "Unable to auto-config arch from toolchain"

How can I fix problem?

Answer (score 9):

You have to specify which toolchain you want, add a `toolchain` flag, for instance for `arm-linux-androidabi-4.6` toolchain:

```
./make-standalone-toolchain.sh --toolchain=arm-linux-androideabi-4.6 --platform=android-9 --install-dir=c:/android-toolchain --ndk-dir=c:/android-ndk-r10d/
```

You can find the list of available toolchains in your `c:/android-ndk-r10d/toolchains` directory.